# Python me lanza el error getopt option not recognized

Tags: python

Querría utilizar `getopt` para obtener *input from command line argument* (entradas desde argumentos de línea de comandos):

```
import getopt
import sys

version = '1.0'
verbose = False
output_filename = 'default.out'

print('ARGV      :', sys.argv[1:])

options, remainder = getopt.gnu_getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'o:v', ['output=', 
                                                         'verbose',
                                                         'version=',
                                                         ])
```

Pero cuando ejecuto `python convert.py -i [input file name]` obtengo el siguiente error:

> GetoptError: option -f not recognized

¿Cuál podría ser el problema?

El objetivo final es utilizar este código para convertir ficheros `.csv` en archivos `.xes`:

```
import sys
import getopt
import logging
import getpass
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring, Comment,     ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom
import csv
from datetime import datetime


def prettify(elem):
    rough_string = tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml()


def parse_time(time):
    time = datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return datetime.strftime(time.astimezone(), '{}%z'.format(time.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')))


def parse_csv(file):
    if file.split('.')[-1] != 'csv':
        logging.error("file format error")
        exit(1)
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, strict=True)
        for row in reader:
            if reader.line_num != 1:
                if not row[0] in instances:
                    instances[row[0]] = [row[1:]]
                else:
                    instances[row[0]].append(row[1:])


def parse_header(root):
    extensions = [Element('extension', {
        'name': 'Concept',
        'prefix': 'concept',
        'url': 'http://www.xes-standard.org/concept.xesext'
    }), Element('extension', {
        'name': 'Time',
        'prefix': 'time',
        'url': 'http://www.xes-standard.org/time.xesext'
    }), Element('extension', {
        'name': 'Organizational',
        'prefix': 'org',
        'url': 'http://www.xes-standard.org/org.xesext'
    }), Element('extension', {
        'name': 'Lifecycle',
        'prefix': 'lifecycle',
        'url': 'http://www.xes-standard.org/lifecycle.xesext'
    })
]
    global_trace = Element('global', {'scope': 'trace'})
    global_trace.append(Element('string', {'key': 'concept:name', 'value': 'unknown'}))
    global_event = Element('global', {'scope': 'event'})
    global_event_attrs = [ Element('string', {'key': 'concept:instance', 'value': 'unknown'}),
    Element('string', {'key': 'concept:name', 'value': 'unknown'}),
    Element('date', {'key': 'time:timestamp', 'value': '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+08:00'}),
    Element('string', {'key': 'lifecycle:transition', 'value': 'unknown'}),
    Element('int', {'key': 'duration', 'value': '0'}),
    Element('string', {'key': 'org:role', 'value': 'unknown'}),
    Element('string', {'key': 'org:resource', 'value': 'unknown'})
]
    global_event.extend(global_event_attrs)
    globals = [global_trace, global_event]
    classifiers = [
    Element('classifier', {'name': 'Activity', 'keys': 'concept:name'}),
    # Element('classifier', {'name': 'Activity and Transition', 'keys': 'concept:name lifecycle:transition'})
]
    strings = [
    Element('string', {'key': 'concept:name', 'value': 'EIS2018-HW1'}),
    Element('string', {'key': 'creator', 'value': username})
]

    root.append(Comment('Generated by csv2xes'))
    root.extend(extensions)
    root.extend(globals)
    root.extend(classifiers)
    root.extend(strings)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        logging.error('parameter error')
        exit(1)

    input_file = ''
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hi:')
    for op, value in opts:
        if op == '-i':
            input_file = value
        else:
            exit(1)

    username = getpass.getuser()
    instances = dict()

    log = Element('log', {'xes.version': '2.0', 'xmlns': 'http://www.xes-standard.org'})
    parse_header(log)
    parse_csv(input_file)

    count = 0
    for instance in instances.items():
        trace = SubElement(log, 'trace')
        trace.append(Element('string', {'key': 'concept:name', 'value': instance[0]}))
        for element in instance[1]:
            start_event = Element('event')
            # complete_event = Element('event')
            start_attrs = [
            Element('string', {'key': 'concept:instance', 'value': str(count)}),
            Element('string', {'key': 'concept:name', 'value': element[4]}),
            Element('date', {'key': 'time:timestamp', 'value': parse_time(element[1])}),
            Element('string', {'key': 'lifecycle:transition', 'value': 'start'}),
            Element('int', {'key': 'duration', 'value': element[3]}),
            Element('string', {'key': 'org:role', 'value': element[5]}),
            Element('string', {'key': 'org:resource', 'value': element[0]})
        ]
        '''
        complete_attrs = [
            Element('string', {'key': 'concept:instance', 'value': str(count)}),
            Element('string', {'key': 'concept:name', 'value': element[4]}),
            Element('date', {'key': 'time:timestamp', 'value': parse_time(element[2])}),
            Element('string', {'key': 'lifecycle:transition', 'value': 'complete'}),
            Element('int', {'key': 'duration', 'value': element[3]}),
            Element('string', {'key': 'org:role', 'value': element[5]}),
            Element('string', {'key': 'org:resource', 'value': element[0]})
        ]
        '''
            start_event.extend(start_attrs)
            # complete_event.extend(complete_attrs)
            trace.append(start_event)
            # trace.append(complete_event)
            count += 1

    elementTree = ElementTree(element=log)
    elementTree.write('{}.xes'.format(input_file.split('.')[0]), encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
    # print(prettify(log))
```

No estoy segura de cómo funciona este código para convertir ficheros, ni por qué tengo que utilizar `getopt`. Si alguien tiene una idea de las razones de su uso, ¡me interesa también!.

Además, cualquier cosa que hago, tengo problemas con la `getoption error`, también utilizando otros ejemplos de uso de esta función presentados en internet, y no entiendo por qué.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Es lo normal tal y como tienes el código. ¿Podrías poner qué parámetros deseas implementar y qué parámetros has tecleado?

Comment: ¿por qué es normal? he añadido informaciones, no sé si es un poco más claro... ¡gracias!

Comment: Es normal porque en ningún momento le has dicho que `-f` fuera un parámetro permitido. No necesito el código de conversión, sólo qué parámetros usará tu aplicación. Algo "formal" como `conversor.py -f <archivo> [-n <n° elementos]` o cualquier notación informal o explicación como "el parámetro `-f` es obligatorio y tras él se indica un archivo, el parámetro `-n` es opcional y tras él se indica un número".

Comment: ¿y es necesario decirlo? sí, aquí está la línea: '$ python convert.py -i [input file name]'

Comment: Si quieres que redacte una respuesta con los parámetros de `getopt()` que necesitas, sí. Por ejemplo, `'o:v', ['output=', 'verbose', 'version=']` significa: un `-o` con un parámetro tras él (de ahí los dos puntos `:`), `-v` sin parámetro adicional, `--output=<parametro>`, `--verbose` sin parámetro y `--version=<parametro>`. Las opciones obligatorias o no se implementan en código. Como ves no hay nada más en cuanto a opciones, por eso te da error el `-f`.

Comment: Eso no concuerda con el mensaje de error que te está dando. Pone `GetoptError: option -f not recognized` (intento de usar `-f`como parámetro y éste no estar contemplado) y según tú has usado `-i`, que tampoco está indicado en tu llamada a `getopt()`.

Comment: ¡gracias, creo que he entendido! todavía tengo problemas con mi codigo, pero solo por razones de 'file format error' con la fecha y la hora

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta bastante amplia explicando el funcionamiento de `getopt`, cómo capturar la excepción y cómo tratar las opciones proporcionadas a través de la línea de comandos. Espero que tanto los comentarios intercambiados como la respuesta hayan podido serte de ayuda para entender cómo funciona y adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Comment: sí, gracias, ahora sé cómo utilizarlo

Answer (score 0):

La excepción que estás sufriendo es debido a que proporcionas un parámetro que no está configurado en tu llamada a `getopt`. Puede ser capturado por un bloque `try/except` para permitir que la ejecución continúe o bien detenerla.

Antes de nada debes comprender cómo funciona `getopt`, sobre todo qué significan sus parámetros y los valores de retorno, así que partiré de una versión un poco modificada de tu código:

```
import getopt
import sys

version = '1.0'
verbose = False
output_filename = 'default.out'

print('ARGV    :', sys.argv[1:])

try:
    opciones, resto = getopt.gnu_getopt(
        sys.argv[1:],
        'o:v',
        [
            'output=',
            'verbose',
            'version=',
        ]
    )
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    # Mostramos el mensaje de error y salimos
    print("Error: " + str(err))
    sys.exit(2)

print('opciones:', opciones)
print('resto   :', resto)
```

El primer parámetro (`sys.argv[1:]`) es una matriz de datos que serán procesados en busca de opciones. En este caso se hace uso de `sys.argc` que contiene todos los parámetros de la línea de comandos empezando por el elemento `0` que contiene el nombre del script tal y como fue invocado (por eso usa solo del `1` en adelante).

El segundo parámetro (`'o:v'`) contiene una cadena de caracteres que representa las opciones de un único carácter que serán permitidos precedidos por `-`. En este caso se permite la opción `-o <parámetro>` o `-o<parámetro>` (`o:`, los dos puntos indican que requiere un parámetro adicional, separado o no por un espacio en blanco de la opción) y `-v`.

El tercer parámetro es una matriz de opciones de múltiples caracteres que deben comenzar por `--`. En nuestro caso `'output='` indica que puede usarse `--output=parámetro` (el `=` al final indica la necesidad de proporcionar un parámetro a la opción), el elemento `'verbose'` permite usar `--verbose` y `'version='` usar `--version=parámetro` (de nuevo se hace uso del `=` al final para indicar la necesidad de proporcionar un parámetro).

Tras explicar el significado veamos la salida de varias llamadas a la aplicación:

```
$ python3 poc.py 
ARGV    : []
opciones: []
resto   : []
$ python3 poc.py -a
ARGV    : ['-a']
Error: option -a not recognized
$ python3 poc.py -o
ARGV    : ['-o']
Error: option -o requires argument
$ python3 poc.py --prueba
ARGV    : ['--prueba']
Error: option --prueba not recognized
$ python3 poc.py --version
ARGV    : ['--version']
Error: option --version requires argument
$ python3 poc.py -o salida.txt --version 1.2 entrada.txt
ARGV    : ['-o', 'salida.txt', '--version', '1.2', 'entrada.txt']
opciones: [('-o', 'salida.txt'), ('--version', '1.2')]
resto   : ['entrada.txt']
$ python3 poc.py -o salida.txt --version 1.2 -- --parece_trampa
ARGV    : ['-o', 'salida.txt', '--version', '1.2', '--', '--parece_trampa']
opciones: [('-o', 'salida.txt'), ('--version', '1.2')]
resto   : ['--parece_trampa']
```

A destacar:

- Todo lo que se proporcione como parámetro que no comience por `-` o `--` se agrega a `resto`.
- Todo lo que se proporcione después de un `--` a secas (como el ejemplo de `--parece_trampa`) se agrega a `resto` empiece o no por `-` o `--`.
- Se producen excepciones en caso de que:

  - Se use una opción no configurada.
  - Se use una opción configurada que requiera parámetro y éste no se proporcione.

Ahora faltaría tratar las opciones recibidas para cambiar los parámetros de la aplicación:

```
# Iteramos por cada elemento de las opciones
for opcion, argumento in opciones:
    if opcion in ("-v", "--verbose"):
        verbose = True
    elif opcion in ("-o", "--output"):
        output_filename = argumento
    elif opcion == "--version":
        version = argumento
# Mostramos el estado final de las variables
print(
    'version:', version,
    ', verbose:', verbose,
    ', output_filename:', output_filename
)
```

Si probamos ahora la aplicación podremos ver los cambios que se producen en las variables:

```
$ python3 poc.py
version: 1.0 , verbose: False , output_filename: default.out
$ python3 poc.py -o salida.txt --version 1.2 entrada.txt
version: 1.2 , verbose: False , output_filename: salida.txt
$ python3 poc.py -o salida.txt --version 1.2 -- --parece_trampa
version: 1.2 , verbose: False , output_filename: salida.txt
$ python3 poc.py -v
version: 1.0 , verbose: True , output_filename: default.out
$ python3 poc.py -v -o salida.txt
version: 1.0 , verbose: True , output_filename: salida.txt
```

Comment: ¿Muchas gracias!, ahora he bien entendido cómo funciona `getopt`. No había entendido bien el uso de los  argumentos de las líneas de comando, pero así está claro. Esta parte del código funciona ahora.